# Navigation from one MaterialApp to the route on second MaterialApp

Tags: flutter

So this is the case, I have two MaterialApps in a Stack widget, I made it like that so they have separate navigation routes. The problem is, I need to navigate to a page which is on MaterialApp 1 from MaterialApp2.

Even clearer example: Button is on MaterialApp 2, I need to press that button and page on MaterialApp 1 shows up. How do I do this? Whenever I use Navigator.of(context).push() on MaterialApp 2, it of course changes the page on that MaterialApp...

Comment: Can you show your code ?  what you have tried.

Comment: I think you can use global navigation keys, but why do you need two separate MaterialApps in the first place???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary that a Navigator.push() called in a specific MaterialApp widget will be doing push operation on that app's stack. Which MaterialApp's stack to choose depend on the Buildcontext you pass in the push function.
You can do that by saving the BuildContext of both materialApps globally and using whichever you want in Navigator.push().

1. Wrap the children of both MaterialApps in Builder widget to extract the BuildContext of both. Say of app1 it's context1 and app2 it's context2.
2. Save both of them globally using static variables in a different class say "Data".
3. Now while calling Navigator.push() anywhere in your app, instead of simply putting that widget's context in the context parameter use the contexts of the materialApps you saved earliers.

Say you want to push a page on MaterialApp1's stack, do

`Navigator.push(Data.context1,/*Rest of the builder function as it is*/);`

Also instead of using two different MaterialApps just for getting two seperate navigators, you can try using the Navigator widget.